# JQuery $(elmnt + " div").each is there a way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched the internet and not sure even what the question in javascript language terms.  All i'm attempting to do is change the css of div elements inside a selected table row column.  Also I'm looking to do this without too much bloat such as .children() because I only want to select the div children not anything else.
Essentially I have a stored selected table row column in elmnt and would like to traverse each div element inside of it. Here's the code

```
$(elmnt + " div").each(function (i){//also tried $(elmnt.div)...  and $(elmnt +".div")...
    if(this.style.cssFloat==="right")
        this.style.cssFloat="none";
    else
       this.style.cssFloat="right";
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLTableCellElement].div @ ./resources/jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1567

Thanks for any help

Comment: `$(elmnt).children('div')` would also work to select only divs that are direct descendants.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `find` to achieve what you are looking for

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(elmnt).find("div").each(...
```

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
$(elmnt).find('div').each( // ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't concatenate an object and a string, but you can do :

```
$("div", elmnt).css('float', function(_,flt) {
    return flt == 'right' ? 'none' : 'right';
});
```